# createWriteStream 'close' event not being triggered

Tags: node.js, csv, asynchronous, request, fs

I am trying to extract images from a csv file by doing the following:

1. Parsing/streaming in a large csv file using `csv-parse` and the `fs` **createReadStream** method
2. Grabbing each line for processing using `stream-transform`
3. Extraction of image and other row data for processing using the `async` waterfall method.
4. Download and write image to server using `request` and the `fs` **createWriteStream** method

For some reason after the data gets piped into **createWriteStream**, there is some event in which an `async` callback never gets called. I have run this same code only using `request`, without piping to **createWriteStream**, and it works. I've also run **createWriteStream** w/ a `drain` event, and then some how it works? Can anyone explain this to me?

In the code below, `request` is trying to pipe 14,970 images, but the **createWriteStream** `close` or `finish` events only fire 14,895 times, with `error` firing 0 times. Could this be a draining issue? Could `highWaterMark` be exceeded and a write fail could be occurring undetected?

Here is my csv line getting code:

```
var first = true;
var parser = parse();
var transformer = transform( (line, complete) => {
        if(!first)
            extractData(line,complete)
        else {
            first = false;
            complete(null);
        }
    }, 
    () => {
        console.log('Done: parseFile');
    });
fs.createReadStream(this.upload.location).pipe(parser).pipe(transformer);
```

`extractData` function that doesn't always do a required `async` callback:

```
extractData(line,complete){
    var now = new Date();
    var image = { 
        createdAt: now,
        updatedAt: now
    };
    async.waterfall([
        next => { // Data Extraction
            async.forEachOf(line, (data, i, complete) => {
                if(i === 2) image.src = data; 
                if(i === 3) image.importSrc = data;
                complete(null);
            }, err => {
                if(err) throw err;
                next(null);
            });
        },
        next => { // Download Image
            var file = fs.createWriteStream('public/'+image.src);
            var sendReq = request.get(image.importSrc);
            sendReq.on('response', response => {
                if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
                    this.upload.report.image.errors++;
                    return next(null);
                } 
            });
            sendReq.on('error', err => {
                this.upload.report.image.errors++;
                next(null);
            });
            sendReq.pipe(file);
            file.on('finish', () => {
                this.upload.report.image.inserts++;
                file.close(next); // Close file and callback
            });
            file.on('error', err => {
                this.upload.report.image.errors++;
                next(null);
            });
        }
    ], err => {
        if(err) throw err;
        complete(null);
    });
}
```

As suggested by @mscdex, I've also tried switching out `finish` for his replacement `close` approach.

Answer (score 0):

`file.close(next);` is unnecessary as the file stream is closed automatically by default. What you can do instead is to listen for the `close` event to know when the file descriptor for the stream has been closed. So replace the entire `finish` event handler with:

```
file.on('close', () => {
  this.upload.report.image.inserts++;
  next(null);
});
```

Comment: I tried the above and it didn't work. It attempts to download and requests 14,970 images, but `close` is only called 14,895 times. Also `error` is called 0 times.